# How to find the sum of the areas of all odd-sided squares in a $9*8$ Grid.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, contest-math, combinations, problem-solving

> Find the sum of the areas of all odd-sided squares in a $9*8$ Grid.

**What I Tried**: As a general formula, I know that the number of squares in a $9*8$ Grid would be :-
$$\rightarrow \frac{M(M + 1)(3N - M + 1)}{6}$$
Where $N \geq M$. So putting $N = 9$ and $M = 8$ gives :-
$$\rightarrow \frac{8(9)(20)}{6}$$
Which is a total of $240$ squares.

Now, I am wondering whether there is a formula for finding the number of odd-sided squares, or even-sided squares, or both. For example in a $2*2$ grid you will have $4$ odd-sided and $1$ even sided square, assuming each small square's length to be $1$ unit.

I also have no idea on finding the area, because in that case I have no choice but to count the different odd-sided and sized squares independently, and then find out their area and add then up. The answer is given to be :-
$$\rightarrow \sum\limits_{r=1}^4 (11-2r)(10-2r)(2r-1)^2 $$

How do we do this? How are we even getting the answer? 
Can anyone help me? Thank You.

Comment: The first formula comes from $\sum_{r=1}^{m} (m - r + 1) (n−r + 1)$. Now in the second case, we need to take only odd values of $r$ in that summation. There is a closed form - replace $r$ with $2r-1$ or $2r+1$ and adjust the increments and limits of $r$ accordingly. It is easier to do it first for odd $m$ and for even $m$. Wolfram Alpha gives a closed form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Take cases: I.e. when the side of square is $1,3,5,7$ units

**More Bigger Hint**:-

> To generalise let the square be of side $2r-1$ . As the grid is $9*8$  the number of such squares possible is the ways in which we can select $2r$ lines which are consecutive (visualising helps) from $9+1$ lines *times* the number of ways in which we can select $2r$ lines consecutively from $8+1$ lines which is $(11-2r)(10-2r)$.

Comment: Oh I got it, since we are finding the area we are multiplying it with $(2r - 1)^2$ , and we are summing it up for the $4$ cases of $1,3,5,7$ sided squares.

Comment: @Anonymous of course!